# Html input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm looking for a way to validate that no input element contains within a form contains any html tags or values such as `<?` on client side as value. I searched for it around several sources, including general search in Google.

I know that this issue is resolved in server side on various technologies, but I want to bring forth better user experience, with no default error messages or even raising a request to the server.

EDIT:
Specifically, it will be used in specific input element, that their input should not be defined as html tags and such...

Comment: As a rule of thumb, people often want to talk about things using those characters, so it is better to escape them then to try to block them.

Comment: What are you planning to do if you're not raising a request to the server?

Comment: It should also be noted that you must validate or escape the input server-side to prevent script injection by circumventing your client-side validation.

Comment: I want to catch these 'things' on client side before they get to the server. The request will be raised only if they don't contain such 'things'.

Comment: Make sure to sanitize on the server too. It is very easy to circumvent client side validation

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara this is handled in the server by the technologies I'm using on all of the web apps I'm working on.

Comment: @lionheart That makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: @mplungjan How is this a duplicate? 1. I don't ask to remove < by its own, for example. 2. there is no valid answer there.

Comment: For whom it may concern, please review this link... 

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: How is that not a duplicate - you want to test the content - the duplicate can block or test depending on what you decide in the test

Comment: @mplungjan better answer to my question is: there is no way, then... blocking or the conditions in the other "duplication" doesn't answer the question. I better use escaping then block '<'. Nevertheless, thanks.

Comment: The better user experience without warning is to allow the string to be sent to the server and sanitized there. The correct sanitation is then of course to NOT embed the html in a retrieval request since it can harm the new recipient

Comment: Have you thought about a regex?

Comment: @FrankConijn I'm not in favor of regex with checking HTML syntax - but it can narrow down most of the cases. I don't have a problem with people writing <div specifically, but I wouldn't want them to <div>. This is why I requested an HTML template checker and not just < cleaner or 'sanitizer'. It's much more accurate. I decided to write my own HTML tester, because it seems to be fine-grained to my purpose. Thanks...